# SneakyJoystick question in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I currently have a SneakyJoystick up and running. It works fine, it moves the sprite around the screen. I already have it so it will flip the sprite's image when the joysticks degrees is to the left. But how do i make it so if it was moving left and then becomes inactive, the sprite won't automatically flip back? This is really confusing to me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a scheduled selector function in your program that checks the movement of your joystick after every second (or whatever the interval). I mean the code where you are checking if the joystick is towards left (joystick.velociy). So this selector will be called continuously, no matter your joystick is active or not. So when your joystick moves to left, you can flip the sprite and you can set define a boolean flag "isFlipped=true". And in the same selector method that you can check if joystick is not moving and "isFlipped=true" then you can flip back your sprite and set the flag false.

Comment: Okay. And since you mentioned it, how do I set the interval for a selector function?

Comment: [self schedule:@selector(your_function:) interval:0.5]; .... Something like that. The interval is in seconds.

Comment: okay thanks for the quick reply! Now one more thing. I am using a SneakyJoystick, as you know, and it moves the sprite just fine, but it moves it really slowly. How do I make it so it moves faster? [Here](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/) is the link for the SneakyJoystick.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313: you can check the velocity of joystick by "joystick.velocity" and it gives you a CGPoint where you have x and y component of the velocity. Its upto you how fast you want to move your sprite. How you move your sprite??? if you do it by calling runAction on your sprite then just reduce the time interval to make it fast.

Comment: I just use the joystick velocity to move it. I will change the function so it moves faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is advised to multiple the velocity by an arbitary amount and the delta value passed in to the update routine so that things move more smoothly.  That will ensure that the final movement of the player is OK.  I have seen people use a value between 50 and 200 for average movement.

eg,
    CGPoint velocity = ccpMult(moveStick.velocity, 200 * delta);